# Django session issue while redirecting to other

Tags: python, django

I am developing the e-commerce website with Django, So after successful payment through Paytm payment gateway(Integration testing)

I have a session issue in the local server, after redirecting from Paytm test integration portal to a payment success page (local server ), user session logout automatically while I am on the payment success page.

Payment.html file

```
 {% extends 'shop/base.html' %}
 {% load static %}
 {% block title%}
  Paytm merchant payment page
 {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
<h1>Redirecting you to the merchant....</h1>
<h1>Please do not refresh your page....</h1>


<form action="https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process"  
  method="post" 
  name="paytm">

 {{ form.as_p }}
{% for key, value in param_dict.items %}
<input type="hidden" name="{{key}}" value="{{value}}">
{% endfor %}
</form>
<script>
    document.paytm.submit()
</script>
 {% endblock %}
```

paymentstatus.html file

```
{% extends 'shop/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title%}Shoppy hub{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="container">

<div class="col my-4">

    <h1>Payment status regarding your order Id : {{response.ORDERID}}</h1>
    {% if response.RESPCODE == '01' %}
    <h3>Amount paid:{{response.TXNAMOUNT}} </h3>
    <h3><img style="height:50px;"src="/static/img/success.png" >Your order 
    has been received successfully</h3 >

    <h3>Thank you for your purchase! </h3>
    {% else %}
    <h2> <img style="height:50px;"src="/static/img/fail.jpg" >Your order 
    has been failed</h2 >
    {% endif%}

  </div>

  </div>
   {% endblock %}
   {% block js %}
   <script>


   </script>
   {% endblock %}
```

[Checkout page(user logged in)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72cDm.png)

[Payment page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhTuT.png)

[Payment success page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sseK6.png)

Session issue might be due to the redirecting from  (Django local server) to the Paytm payment portal, But in the payment portal (product price and user name) is being successfully forwarded in integration testing payment page, but after the payment is successfully done and it redirects to the payment success page(local server). At that time user gets logout automatically, although the amount is displayed correctly on the success page.

So guys please help me to maintain the session while redirecting to the other page and then redirecting back to the local server.

settings.py

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
'cart.apps.CartConfig',
'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
'orders.apps.OrdersConfig',
'about.apps.AboutConfig',
'contact.apps.ContactConfig',
'search.apps.SearchConfig',
'offers.apps.OffersConfig',
 ]

 MIDDLEWARE = [
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]
```

How can I identify key /value  in response headers,Response header(After Logged In):HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 05:21:02 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 39759
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie:  sessionid=frnyglh4tzkp2fgqjv2p3acs2sut5to9; expires=Thu, 28 May 2020 05:21:02 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax

After Payment Done:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 14 May 2020 05:30:06 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.7.3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Vary: Cookie
Content-Length: 3652
Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=19FoDcypCYyUBy2DHCnxkMn3Zfjn9RufUoqiVKBu4duZxcqNhrHL5MAtqtg9ZNdh; expires=Thu, 13 May 2021 05:30:05 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax
Set-Cookie:  sessionid=g2ctxjjt8llz8d7khdub6aa3fvcxxkcy; expires=Thu, 28 May 2020 05:30:05 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax

Comment: As far as I recall, django stores session on the browser as a cookie. are you using the django SessionMiddleware?

I suggest taking a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: I have already used middleware  in settings.py.

Comment: @MenyIssakov  please help me to solve this issue

Comment: If you check the server response in your browser. does your response has cookies in it?

Comment: Ok I will check it and post the server  responses  Screenshots

Comment: This are the last server responses that I got while in payment successfull page
[12/May/2020 11:47:30] "GET /shop/13/55-ltr-rucksack-trekking-bag/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5941
[12/May/2020 11:47:32] "POST /cart/add/13/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[12/May/2020 11:47:32] "GET /cart/detail/%20 HTTP/1.1" 200 6709
[12/May/2020 11:47:36] "GET /orders/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5622
[12/May/2020 11:47:54] "POST /orders/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4730
order successful
[12/May/2020 11:50:03] "POST /orders/order/handlerequest/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3652
[12/May/2020 11:50:04] "GET /static/img/success.png HTTP/1.1" 200 7716

Comment: Please open the Chrome Dev tools -> Network.

Click on the relevant HTTP request.

Select headers.

Paste the content of the Response headers (we're looking for the cookies 
key/value).

Comment: Ok, I will check out it out and post it

Comment: I have added header response in my post at bottom

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to success page after successsful payment try to use
HttpResponseRedirect('/success/') instead of render('...')

i hope your problem will be solved..